# Cannot write dataframe into hive table after using UDF in Pyspark

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, user-defined-functions

I am trying to extract first element of probability column (vector data type) using UDF in Pyspark. I was able to get the new dataframe with extracted values in probability column. I also checked the data type of probability column which has changed from vector to float. But I am not able to write the dataframe into hive table. I get numpy module not found error. Deploy mode is client. Is there a workaround other than installing numpy in all the worker nodes ?

Code -

```
spark = (SparkSession
.builder
.appName("Model_Scoring")
.master('yarn')
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
)

hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()
hive.setDatabase("hc360_models")

final_ads = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://DATAHUB/datahube/feature_engineering/final_ads.parquet")

model = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/fitted_model_new/")

first_element=udf(lambda v:float(v[0]),FloatType())

out = model.transform(final_ads)

out = out.withColumn("probability",first_element("probability")).drop('features').drop('rawPrediction')

out.show(10)
out.write.mode("append").format(HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR).option("table","test_hypertension_table_final3").save()

spark.stop()
```

Error -

ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function _parse_datatype_json_string at 0x7f83370922a8>, (u'{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"_0","type":{"type":"udt","class":"org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","pyClass":"pyspark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","sqlType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"type","type":"byte","nullable":false,"metadata":{}},{"name":"size","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"indices","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"integer","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"values","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"double","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"_1","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}',))

Sample data -
[image]

Schema -

StructType(List(StructField(patient_id,IntegerType,true),
StructField(carrier_operational_id,IntegerType,false),
StructField(gender_cde,StringType,true),
StructField(pre_fixed_mpr_qty,DecimalType(38,8),true),
StructField(idx_days_in_gap,DecimalType(11,1),true),
StructField(age,DecimalType(6,1),true),
StructField(post_fixed_mpr_adh_ind,DecimalType(2,1),true),
StructField(probability,FloatType,true),
StructField(prediction,DoubleType,false),
StructField(run_date,TimestampType,false)))

Comment: Please add sample data and schema of it

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the data and the schema. @Manish